# Limit number of searchresults from a simple jQuery keyup searchbox

Tags: jquery, search, limit

Im trying to get a certain number of searchresults append when making a search in my #searchbox to be able not to append too much searchlistings in the result div. Im stalled here, no clue how to proceed.

```
var jsonData;

            $.getJSON("<?php echo base_url(); ?>/show_controller", function(json){
                jsonData = json;

            });


        $("#searchbox").keyup(function()
        {
            var searchvalue = $("#searchbox").val();
            $("#searchresult").empty();
            $("#step2").remove();
            $("#searchresult").append("<table>");
            $("#searchresult").append("<td><b>Name</b></td>");
            $("#searchresult").append("<td><b>Description</b></td>");
            $("#searchresult").append("<td><b>Manufacturer</b></td>");
            $("#searchresult").append("<td><b>Batch</b></td>");
            $("#searchresult").append("<td><b>Sign for registration</b></td>");
            for(var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++)
                {

                    if(jsonData[i]['Name'].indexOf(searchvalue) != -1 || jsonData[i]['Desc'].indexOf(searchvalue) != -1)
                    {
                        $("#searchresult").append("<tr>");
                        $("#searchresult").append("<td>" + jsonData[i]['Name'] + "</td>");
                        $("#searchresult").append("<td>" + jsonData[i]['Desc'] + "</td>");
                        $("#searchresult").append("<td>Manufacturer(nodata yet)</td>");
                        $("#searchresult").append("<td>Batch(nodata yet)</td>");
                        $("#searchresult").append("<td class='listdata'><input type='checkbox' class='user' id='" + jsonData[i]['id'] + "'></td>'"); 
                        $("#searchresult").append("</tr>");
                    }



                }
            $("#searchresult").append("</table>");
            $("#content").append("<input type='submit' id='step2' value='Next >>'>");
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this in the PHP code which the JSON is calling.

If for whatever reason you can't, then amend the following line:

```
//for(var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++)
var maxLimit = 15;
var limit = jsonData.length < maxLimit ? jsonData.length : maxLimit ;
for(var i = 0; i < limit ; i++)
```

Obviously this will limit the loop to 15 iterations, you can amend that as needed.

I'd also suggest you change the number of `.append()` calls you're making. It would be a lot more efficient if you built the entire table row as a string or jquery object and only appended it once, eg.

```
var tableHeadings = "<table>\
    <td><b>Name</b></td>\
    <td><b>Description</b></td>\
    <td><b>Manufacturer</b></td>\
    <td><b>Batch</b></td>\
    <td><b>Sign for registration</b></td>";
$("#searchresult").append(tableHeadings);
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading your code right your jsonData variable contains all possible search results and then your keyup function filters within those search results and at the moment it displays all matching results but you want to limit it to only display the first x items that match?

If so then you just need to keep a count of how many things you've already appended and stop when that count goes over some preset limit or when you run out of data (whichever comes first).

I won't repeat the entire function here, but something like this:

```
var maxResults = 10; // or whatever your limit is

for(var i = 0, count = 0; i < jsonData.length && count < maxResults; i++)
{
   if(jsonData[i]['Name'].indexOf(searchvalue) != -1 || jsonData[i]['Desc'].indexOf(searchvalue) != -1)
   {
      // only increment count when you find a match
      count++;

      $("#vaccine_searchresult").append("<tr>");
      $("#vaccine_searchresult").append("<td>" + jsonData[i]['Name'] + "</td>");
      // etc
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can limit it by checking the loop variable `i` - say if it goes beyond 10 then break the for loop.

Better way would be to pass `max` parameter to your server side url that returns the search results so that it will only return max results.

OTOH, you may add  `overflow:auto` css to your div to get scroll bars when there are many search results.

Comment: Great! had thought about the overflow property but dont know if thats going to sit well with the layout.